# Can we edit the mapping after exicution of session and workflow in Informatica Powercenter 9.5.0

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, information-schema

1. I have created a source and target tables and mapping.
2. Created session and workflow.
3. Executed the workflow also.

**Problem** : In mapping i have to add a one more connection from transformation to target table.

**Error** : This mapping is read-only.

**Question** : Can we edit the mapping after it's execution?

Comment: What do you mean by the mapping is readonly?

Comment: There may be multiple reasons -
check if someone else already opened the mapping? 
Check if you opened it from some other laptop?
looks like there is a lock on the mapping. Close all your/other user's session. Ask everyone to close your mapping.
Check if your connection to Infa designer to repository is intact. 
Close designer and re-open it.

 - After or during execution there should be no lock on the mapping.

Comment: Mappings can be edited while being executed without any problem. Just keep in mind that changes will not affect the execution. For the execution there is a copy created. All your changes can be effective only upon next run. Here in your case it's just someone else editing it. Or your own session on a different machine.

Comment: Thanks, @Koushik.Works perfectly when I closed all tools and restarted my laptop.